# Ubuntu 18.04 VM is not getting connected to the Internet

Tags: virtual-machine, ubuntu-18.04, virtualhost, proxmox

I am new to proxmox. I have created a VM having the Ubuntu 18.04 template on top of Proxmox OS. The problem is it is not getting connected to the internet. The proxmox server has an active LAN Connection.

```
$ ping 8.8.8.8
connect: Network is unreachable
-----------------------------------------------
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# ifupdown has been replaced by netplan(5) on this system.  See
# /etc/netplan for current configuration.
# To re-enable ifupdown on this system, you can run:
#    sudo apt install ifupdown

-----------------------------------------------------------
$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default 
qlen 1000
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0@if26: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group 
default qlen 1000
link/ether f2:15:10:e9:c3:83 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
inet6 fe80::f015:10ff:fee9:c383/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
---------------------------------------------------------
$ /etc/resolv.conf
# --- BEGIN PVE ---
search infra.vitwit.com
nameserver 8.8.8.8
# --- END PVE ---
```

Answer (score 0):

if it's your Ubuntu virtual machine network interface eth0
there is no set IP address, and of course, you can not connect to the internet.
Also, make sure your DHCP network can distribute IP addresses to Proxmox or enter a static address.
show the output of those commands: ip link, ip a, ip route